# How to validate email id and password & confirm password in php

Tags: php, email

i doing register form in php. i dont know how to validate my entered email and (password and confirm password) in php. For email if i enter same id "It should tell my email alread registered" and for password and confirmpassword should check whether it same or not. I have tried email in my coding. it throwing error email already registed but i want to display error in login screen. Please help for this two things. i am very new to php. sorry for my poor english. 
I have return my code below,

```
<?php
require('config.php');
// If the values are posted, insert them into the database.
if (isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])){
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $cpassword = $_POST['confirmpassword'];
    $slquery = "SELECT 1 FROM register WHERE email = '$email'";
    $selectresult = mysql_query($slquery);
    if(mysql_num_rows($selectresult)>0)
    {
        die('email already exists');
    }

    $query = "INSERT INTO `register` (username, password,confirmpassword, email) VALUES ('$username', '$password', '$cpassword', '$email')";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    if($result){
        $msg = "User Created Successfully.";
    }
   }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Login screen</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    .register-form{
        width: 500px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 10px;
        padding: 10px;
        background : #c4c4c4;
        border-radius: 10px;
        -webkit-border-radius:10px;
        -moz-border-radius:10px;
    }
    .register-form form input{padding: 5px;}
    .register-form .btn{
        background: #726E6E;
        padding: 7px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        text-decoration: none;
        width: 50px;
        display: inline-block;
        color: #FFF;
    }
    .register-form .register{
        border: 0;
        width: 60px;
        padding: 8px;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="register-form">
    <?php
        if(isset($msg) & !empty($msg)){
        echo $msg;
    }
    ?>
    <?php
    if(isset($errormes))
    {
        echo $errormes;
    }
    ?>
        <h1>Register</h1>
        <form action="" method="POST">
            <p><label>User Name: </label>
            <input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username">
            </p>
            <p><label>E-Mail&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; :</label>
            <input id="email" name="email" type="email">
            </p>
            <p><label>Password&nbsp;&nbsp; :</label>
            <input id="password" name="password" type="password">
            </p>
            <p><label>confirm Password &nbsp;&nbsp; :</label>
            <input id="confirmpassword" name="confirmpassword" type="password">
            </p>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="register" class="btn register">
            <a class="btn" href="login.php">Login</a>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The die(), function will effectivly stop the execution of your script. This meaning no more code will run after that line.

You probably would like to use something as a header() to redirect the user to a page dispalying the incorrect loginscreen.

Or you could include the page, like you do in your example. Something like this:

```
<?php
require('config.php');
// If the values are posted, insert them into the database.
if (isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])){
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $cpassword = $_POST['confirmpassword'];
    $slquery = "SELECT 1 FROM register WHERE email = '$email'";
    $selectresult = mysql_query($slquery);
    if(mysql_num_rows($selectresult)>0)
    {
         $msg = 'email already exists';
    }
    elseif($password != $cpassword){
         $msg = "passwords doesn't match";
    }
    else{
          $query = "INSERT INTO `register` (username, password,confirmpassword, email) VALUES ('$username', '$password', '$cpassword', '$email')";
          $result = mysql_query($query);
          if($result){
             $msg = "User Created Successfully.";
          }
    }
   }
?>
```

replace your first code block with this.

Comment: Thanks for your help sir, i got it. At a same time how to check the confirmpassword and password field are same in php.

Comment: You should mark this answer as correct if it helped you and by doing this close the question.

Comment: Just a note: if you're processing logins on a separate php page, the $msg should be a $_SESSION['msg'] var to transfer to page you're redirecting to.

Comment: @GaryHayes you are correct, but since OP isn't in the example I didn't include that in this solution either

Comment: Thanks a lot sir, you gave me a confident. Thanks for spending time for me.

Comment: at the top of each php page, your scripts should start with opening the session, as such: <?php session_start();

Comment: @PhilipG I know. But he seems new to php, if asking how to validate log ins, so I figured I'd add a little extra to help along.

Comment: @PhilipG use array variable to display error messages, so that users knows what he/she needs to correct

Answer (score 1):

First, Welcome to PHP!

Let me tell you one thing,
it is not a good practice to write source codes all-together in the same way as they are executed. Use **function**s which has many advantages. As you are new in PHP and you are just running a simple requirement, here I have the best solution for you.

Now please note:

1. I have used three user defined functions.
2. Replaced your `$msg` and `$errormes` with `echo`(it will print the
   message on top of your HTML content). Also it is good to keep your PHP and HTML separately(not mixing together unless you really want it).

Here is the full code. Try this:

```
<?php

require_once('config.php');

// function for email validation
function is_valid_email($mail)
{
     if (empty($mail)) {
         echo "Email is required.";
         return false;
     } else {
         $email = test_input($mail);
         // check if e-mail address is well-formed
         if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
           echo "Invalid email format."; 
           return false;
     } 
     // now check if the mail is already registered
     $slquery = "SELECT 1 FROM register WHERE email = '$email'";
     $selectresult = mysql_query($slquery);
     if(mysql_num_rows($selectresult)>0) {
       echo 'This email already exists.';
       return false;
     }
     // now returns the true- means you can proceed with this mail
     return true;
}

// function for password verification
function is_valid_passwords($pass,$confirmpass) 
{
     // Your validation code.
     if (empty($pass)) {
         echo "Password is required.";
         return false;
     } 
     else if ($pass != $confirmpass) {
         // error matching passwords
         echo 'Your passwords do not match. Please type carefully.';
         return false;
     }
     // passwords match
     return true;
}

// function for creating user
function create_user($username, $password, $cpassword, $email) 
{
      $query = "INSERT INTO `register` (username, password, confirmpassword, email) VALUES ('$username', '$password', '$cpassword', '$email')";
      $result = mysql_query($query);
      if($result){
          return true; // Success
      }else{
          return false; // Error somewhere
      }
}

// Code execution starts here when submit
if (isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])){

    // Reading form values
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $cpassword = $_POST['confirmpassword'];

    if (is_valid_email($email) && is_valid_passwords($password,$cpassword))
    {
        if (create_user($username, $password, $cpassword, $email)) {
              echo 'New User Registered Successfully.';
        }else{
          echo 'Error Registering User!';
        }
    }
    // You don't need to write another 'else' since this is the end of PHP code 
?>

<!-- Here you go with the HTML -->

<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Login screen</title>
        <style type="text/css">
        .register-form{
            width: 500px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 10px;
            padding: 10px;
            background : #c4c4c4;
            border-radius: 10px;
            -webkit-border-radius:10px;
            -moz-border-radius:10px;
        }
        .register-form form input{padding: 5px;}
        .register-form .btn{
            background: #726E6E;
            padding: 7px;
            border-radius: 5px;
            text-decoration: none;
            width: 50px;
            display: inline-block;
            color: #FFF;
        }
        .register-form .register{
            border: 0;
            width: 60px;
            padding: 8px;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="register-form">
            <h1>Register</h1>
            <form action="" method="POST">
                <p><label>User Name: </label>
                <input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username">
                </p>
                <p><label>E-Mail&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; :</label>
                <input id="email" name="email" type="email">
                </p>
                <p><label>Password&nbsp;&nbsp; :</label>
                <input id="password" name="password" type="password">
                </p>
                <p><label>confirm Password &nbsp;&nbsp; :</label>
                <input id="confirmpassword" name="confirmpassword" type="password">
                </p>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="register" class="btn register">
                <a class="btn" href="login.php">Login</a>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Now save this code it in .php file format and run. You will see the way you want it.

Try experiments in PHP. Just google for more. And only ask-if you are stuck for a long time.

Thank you.